# Magento 2 : Rest APi Management payment methods

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento-2.2.5, vault

I need a solution to manage payment methods. 
Ex. Credit cards.
in the web version we have the option to list the cards already used in purchases. (html: //  vault / cards / listaction /).

Is it possible to obtain this information via rest api?
Show, add and remove cards.

Appreciate.

Using magento 2.2.5

Comment: got any solution ?